# Javascript/JQuery Image Cutter

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-manipulation

Okay my last question got no response. I think I didn't ask the way I should do.

Basically my requirement is similar to this one [Programmatically Clip/Cut image using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481351/programmatically-clip-cut-image-using-javascript)

But following that link will result in a rectangle view of any portion of the image but I want to clip it any direction (polygon). Would that be possible?

Comment: how about this http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Comment: @gov: the OP wants arbitrary shapes, not just rectangles.

Comment: @gov my browser detected malware at that link :o

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good way to make an arbitrary polygon shape with the HTML 4 DOM. If you were using canvas I'd say you could do it that way. Your other option would be to just have a transparent png (and gif for IE6) on top and then the image underneath that and absolute positioned similarly to the other answer you referenced.