# How can I cut images off from a big image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I need to order some images with different height and width. I'd like to put them into an array or something.

The problem is these images are on a big image and there is white background behind/between them. I don't have any ideas how to start to cut the big image to small pieces using javascript because they are in random positions, not in order. Any ideas how to start?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is use Image Sprites. If they aren't consistent sizes or locations, you won't be able to do this automatically and will instead have to manually map the dimensions and location of every image. You can also do this in [css - mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481351/programmatically-clip-cut-image-using-javascript

Comment: I don't know any Javascript, but start by changing to black everything that is not white. Now you have a simpler problem that you can solve if you look for Javascript libraries that do *"Connected Component Analysis"*, *"Blob Analysis"*, or segmentation and labelling.