# Crop and resize a group of images without losing quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a following example situation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Riy.jpg

(3 balls inside a picture)

With jquery jquery or css, I want to cut the yellow ball and then change its size (width and height). And so on for the balls I want

I was shown a method in a post: [Programmatically Clip/Cut image using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481351/programmatically-clip-cut-image-using-javascript). But I'm losing image quality and can't change the height or width

There is my code:

```
function setViewport(img, x, y, width, height) {
    if (!img) {
        return;
    }

    img.style.left = "-" + x + "px";
    img.style.top = "-" + y + "px";

    if (width !== undefined) {
        img.parentNode.style.width = width + "px";
        img.parentNode.style.height = height + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of it, you want to manipulate an [image sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), which allows you to select and swap between segments of a single image. You can code your own but there are plugins like [jquery-sprite](https://yangkun.github.io/jquery-sprite/) to simplify managing sprites in jQuery. You'll get better performance using [CSS sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS), however.